# Java Jblas DoubleMatrix vector addition

Tags: java, arrays, performance, linear-algebra, jblas

I feel really stupid asking this, but I can't find a method for adding a row/vector to an index or a specific set of indices.

My current workaround is to
`getRows(int[])` then `addiRowVector(DoubleMatrix)` then `put(Range rs, Range cs, DoubleMatrix x)` : (get rows, add your vector, then put them back)

This seems like a backwards and costly implementation, is there any alternative? Is there something simple I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one row you can do it as in this piece of code using row number for example

```
void oneRow() {
    DoubleMatrix matrix = new DoubleMatrix(new double[][] {
            {11,12,13},
            {21,22,23},
            {31,32,33}});
    DoubleMatrix otherRow = new DoubleMatrix(new double[][] {{-11, -12, -13}});

    int rowNumber = 0;
    DoubleMatrix row = matrix.getRow(rowNumber);
    row.addiRowVector(otherRow);
    matrix.putRow(rowNumber, row);

    System.out.println(matrix);
}
```

as result you'll see

```
[0,000000, 0,000000, 0,000000; 21,000000, 22,000000, 23,000000; 31,000000, 32,000000, 33,000000]
```

for several rows you can use loop using row numbers array for example

```
void multipleRows() {
    DoubleMatrix matrix = new DoubleMatrix(new double[][] {
            {11,12,13},
            {21,22,23},
            {31,32,33}});

    int[] rowNumbers = {0, 2};
    DoubleMatrix otherRows = new DoubleMatrix(new double[][] {
            {-11, -12, -13},
            {-21, -22, -23}});
    int otherRowsNumber = 0;

    for (int r : rowNumbers) {
        DoubleMatrix row = matrix.getRow(r);
        row.addiRowVector(otherRows.getRow(otherRowsNumber++));
        matrix.putRow(r, row);
    }
    System.out.println(matrix);
}
```

and here for result you see

```
[0,000000, 0,000000, 0,000000; 21,000000, 22,000000, 23,000000; 10,000000, 10,000000, 10,000000]
```

Comment: Ahh because 'addiRowVector' is inplace, so when you are manipulating a row, it also manipulates the original DoubleMatrix.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that the row would be a reference rather than a copy.

Comment: To add onto your answer, I think you may not even need to do iterate over a for loop, as there is a function `getRows` that can get a select number of rows and using `addiRowVector` will add to all the rows. Theoretically.

Comment: @AlexanderCarter Yes, you are right, this option is also possible, but this answer seemed clearer